# error con package.json dentro de node_modules (laravel, vagrant)

Tags: laravel, nodejs, npm

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto Laravel, con ubuntu, y estoy con problemas a la hora de actualizar paquetes con npm, el proyecto en si funciona, pero al hacer un npm install tengo el siguiente error:

no such file or directory, open '/home/vagrant/code/app-amparo/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/pkg-dir/package.json.1364889990'

Mi archivo package.json lo tengo en /home/vagrant/code/app-amparo/package.json, que es el directorio del proyecto pero el error lo da con un archivo package.json distinto que está dentro de la carpeta node_modules.

He probado borrando la carpeta node_modules pero al ejecutar npm install vuelve a generar el mismo error.

Este es mi archivo package.json:

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "generate-sw": "workbox injectManifest workbox-config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "7.*",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
},
"dependencies": {
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.1",
    "vuex": "^3.3.0"
}
```

}

Les agradezco si alguien me puede dar una mano.

Comment: Intenta correr npm install en el directorio de windows, homestead no ha actualizado la version de node y algunas dependencias dan lios al ejecutarlas desde vagrant

Comment: Gracias, lo hice, luego volví a ejecutar el npm install dentro de vagrant y me da el siguiente error:

This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2.

Y más adelante vuelve a darme el error original de no encontrar package.json dentro de node_modules